# When to use inputRef.current instead of this.inputRef React.js?

Tags: reactjs, reference

I am puzzled between two syntaxes to access references from the react documentation...All i want to know is when to use inputRef.current to access a reference instead of this.inputRef in react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the reference is created using React.creatRef() a React 16 syntax then you can access it using current property of reference i.e inputRef.current.

**React.createRef()**

```
class User extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.nameField = React.createRef();
        this.onClick = this.focusOnNameField.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            name : props.name
        };

    }
    focusOnNameField = ()=>{
        this.nameField.current.focus();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input ref={this.nameField} name="username" value={this.state.name} />
                <button onClick={this.onClick} >Fous on field</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Without React.createRef()**

```
const User = (props)=>{
    let nameField = null;


   const setRefernce = (inputElement)=>{

        this.nameField = inputElement;
    }
    const onClick = (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.nameField.focus();
    }



    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onClick.bind(this)}>
                <input ref={setRefernce} name="username" value={props.name} />
                <button type="submit" >Focus Input</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As other answers mention, `current` ref property is created by `React.createRef()`, which wasn't originally available in React 16 and was introduced in React 16.3.

Generally it is old syntax (React 15, React 16.0 to 16.2):

```
<input ref={ref => this.inputRef = ref}/>
...
this.inputRef.focus()
```

vs. new syntax (React 16.3 and higher):

```
inputRef = React.createRef();
...
<input ref={this.inputRef}/>
...
this.inputRef.current.focus()
```

New syntax introduces a usable pattern which can be used in older React versions as well:

```
inputRef = { current: null };
...
<input ref={ref => this.inputRef.current = ref}/>
...
this.inputRef.current.focus()
```

The important difference is that `React.createRef()` creates ref object that contains the only property, `current`. This is a pattern to keep ref object reference permanent, even if a ref in `current` property is changing. This way ref object can be passed by reference, even when `current` is initially `null`.

This previously was an antipattern, primarily because a ref is volatile:

```
const ComponentThatAcceptsRefs = ({ inputRef }) => (
  <button onClick={() => inputRef.focus() }>Focus</button>
);
```

and

```
<input ref={ref => this.inputRef = ref}/>
<ComponentThatAcceptsRefs inputRef={this.inputRef}/>
```

In this case it's undefined at the moment when it's passed as a prop. This would require to make `inputRef` prop a getter function to make it work, `getInputRef={() => this.inputRef}`.

While the same thing is possible with ref object (a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uymd7t)):

```
const ComponentThatAcceptsRefs = ({ inputRef }) => (
  <button onClick={() => inputRef.current.focus() }>Focus</button>
);
```

and

```
inputRef = React.createRef();
...
<input ref={this.inputRef}/>
<ComponentThatAcceptsRefs inputRef={this.inputRef}/>
```

There may be more conventional and practical ways in React that don't rely on refs, yet it's possible to do that with ref object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `this.ref` is for React 15, when you assign a ref like so:

```
ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
```

so you can then use `this.textInput`.

For the 'current' syntax that's React 16, using `this.textInput = React.createRef()` in the constructor and then assigning like so:

```
ref={this.textInput}
```

so you then use `this.textInput.current` to access it.

Though a reference to the specific documentation/code that's causing the confusion might help clear things up.