# How to use refs with react-redux's connect HOC on two components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two components which both use the connect HOC.

```js
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import ComponentB from "./ComponentB";
 
class ComponentA extends Component {
  render(){
    return {
        <div>
      <button
       onClick={this.refs.ComponentB.showAlert()}
      >
       Button
      </button>

      <ComponentB
       ref={instance => {
          this.ComponentB = instance.getWrappedInstance();
       }}
      />

    </div>
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {}, null, {withRef: true})(ComponentA)
```

Having ComponantA with the connect HOC gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWrappedInstance' of null"

```js
   export default ComponantA;
```

Not using the HOC would not give me this error.

```js
import {connect} from "react-redux";
class ComponentB extends Component {
 showAlert = () => {
    alert("Please Work");
  }
 
render(){
 return {
     <div>ComponentB</div>
    }
  }
}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {}, null, {withRef: true})(ComponentB)
```

Comment: I edited it, thanks. It's not going to be a typo. It is going to be something about refs, that I don't know how to solve.

Comment: Depends what version of react you are using, if 16 + you may need to be using createRef  - see docs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

Comment: Yes, I am using 16+. Thanks, I will take a look at the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.createRef` was introduced in React 16.3 and is supposed to be used like:

```
this.componentBRef = React.createRef();
...

  <button
   onClick={() => this.componentBRef.current.getWrappedInstance().showAlert()}
  >
   Button
  </button>

  <ComponentB
   ref={this.componentBRef};
   }}
  />
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129104/3731501), the pattern used in `createRef` allows to lazily access a ref through `current` property because `this.componentBRef.current` is initially `null`.

Since Redux is in use, there's a chance that the interaction between components should be performed via Redux instead.

Comment: I added good article https://itnext.io/advanced-react-redux-techniques-how-to-use-refs-on-connected-components-e27b55c06e34

Comment: @zloctb That's true, as for the last React Redux release, there's `forwardRef` option as shown in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182460/3731501