# Forwarding ref in a functional component with react-redux (v. 6.0.1)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use `forwardRef` in my functional component that is also using `react-redux`. My component looks like this:

```
const InfiniteTable = ({
  columns,
  url,
  data,
  stateKey,
  loading,
  loadMore,
  fetchData,
  customRecordParams,
  ...rest
}, ref) => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(0);
  const tableRef = React.createRef();

  console.log(rest);

  let dataSource = data;
  if (customRecordParams) dataSource = _.map(dataSource, customRecordParams);
  if (dataSource.length > FETCH_LIMIT)
    dataSource = _.slice(dataSource, 0, start + FETCH_LIMIT);

  useEffect(() => setupScroll(setStart, tableRef), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadMore) fetchData(url, stateKey, { start });
  }, [start, loadMore]);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    handleSearch: term => console.log(term),
    handleReset: () => console.log("reset")
  }));

  return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={dataSource}
      pagination={false}
      showHeader
      loading={loading}
    />
  );
}; 

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  data: Object.values(state[ownProps.stateKey].data),
  loading: state[ownProps.stateKey].isFetching,
  loadMore: state[ownProps.stateKey].loadMore
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchData },
  null,
  { forwardRef: true }
)(InfiniteTable);
```

However I'm getting this error when trying to use my component with a ref prop:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`InfiniteTable` signature is incorrect, it's [legacy `context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-context.html) that is received as second parameter in functional components, not `ref`. In order to receive ref object to use it with `useImperativeHandle`, a component should be wrapped with `React.forwardRef`.

As [the reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) states,

> useImperativeHandle customizes the instance value that is exposed to parent components when using ref. As always, imperative code using refs should be avoided in most cases. useImperativeHandle should be used with forwardRef

It should be:

```
const InfiniteTable = forwardRef((props, ref) => { ... });

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchData },
  null,
  { forwardRef: true }
)(InfiniteTable);
```